# Conditionally set a variable if it's NULL

Tags: c, variable-assignment, conditional-operator

When stepping through a `sqlite3_stmt`, I'd like to check against a return value of `NULL` rather than store it and check against the stored value.

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
char *email = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10);
if (email == NULL) email = "";
```

And here is what I'd *like* to be doing, minus the double-call to `column`:

```
char *email = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10)) ? (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10) : "";
```

Is there some way to express the second expression more concisely? I have to do a lot of these repetitively, so I'm looking for brevity.

I know this is a problem of control flow rather than a problem with the SQLite API itself but there you have it. I can't think of a good way to do this.

Comment: There _must_ be another question about this, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [GNU extension to C](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) allows the ternary conditional operator to evaluate to its condition if it's true and there's nothing in the first branch:

```
char *email = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10);
email = email ? : "";
```

or, more exactly what you say you're looking for

```
char * email = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10) ? : "";
```

This works when compiling with Clang, too.

Another possibility would be:

```
char *email = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10);
email = (NULL == email) ? email : "";
```

But I think I'd recommend just going with your first option. Make a code snippet if you're doing it a lot.

Comment: That's a very handy extension to know about. Do you have a documentation link for it?

Comment: [Conditionals with Omitted Operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Added to my post.

Comment: Wow, this question got a lot of activity.  

@JoshCaswell, after seeing your initial response, I ended up using `char *email = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10) ? : "";` which is what you ended up saying in your edits above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
char *email;
// Reviewed by "R." to verify sequence point correctness.
email = (email = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10))? email : "";
```

Comment: I would avoid doing this because when I saw it I spent at least 30 seconds verifying that no sequence point rules were violated.That's a waste of the reader's time.

Comment: (There, I fixed it... so the next reader doesn't have to spend 30 seconds re-verifying)

Comment: Haha ok +1 for making me laugh.

Comment: It probably would but I have to agree that I have trouble following it. In fact, even the solution above will probably come back to bite me in six weeks' time...